# Center-aligning text in nav menus

Tags: html, css, alignment, centering

I'm a beginner at `CSS` and am trying to understand how the text in each `li` element in a nav menu can be centered, both vertically and horizontally.

As an example, I am looking at [this particular nav menu](http://pixelsdaily.com/resources/html-css/matte-css-menu/) from David Appleyard:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>CSS Menu</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                padding: 50px;
            }
            /* The CSS Code for the menu starts here */
            #menu {
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                margin: 50px 0;
                padding: 0;
                list-style-type: none;
                background-color: #eee;
                font-size: 13px;
                height: 40px;
                border-top: 2px solid #eee;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
            }
            #menu li {
                float: left;
                margin: 0;              
            }
            #menu li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                padding: 0 20px;
                line-height: 40px;
                color: #666;
            }
            #menu li a:hover, #menu li.active a {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
                color: #999;
            }
            #menu_wrapper ul {margin-left: 12px;}
            #menu_wrapper {padding: 0 16px 0 0; background: url(images/grey.png) no-repeat right;}
            #menu_wrapper div {float: left; height: 44px; width: 12px; background: url(images/grey.png) no-repeat left;}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Grey Menu -->
        <div id="menu_wrapper" class="grey">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How is he getting his `li` text nicely in the middle of the `li` elements? Is he just playing around with `padding` and `line-height`s until he gets it perfect?

Also, on a side note, why does he set his `#menu li a`s to `display:block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the breakdown:

#### `display: block;`

He's doing this because you can give block boxes padding. This is nice because padding is included in the 'clickable' area around the link. Users are accustomed to thinking of menu items as 'buttons,' so it's nice to be able to click more than just the text.

[**View a JSFiddle isolating the padding on an anchor**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnbBf/)

*Note: I only floated the `a` to keep it from extending the entire width of the iframe*

#### Centering horizontally

The padding of the anchor elements is symmetrical, so they're appearing to be centered horizontally. The line that does this is `padding: 0 20px;`. Note that the fact that these block boxes don't extend the full width is because their parents are set to float left.

[**Here's a JSFiddle isolating this centering effect.**](http://jsfiddle.net/66vxN/)

*Note: The parents being floated left is what causes everything to appear on the same line*

#### Centering vertical

Text is centered, by default, about the center of the line. If you're trying to center a single line within a containing element, a nifty trick is to just set the `line-height` to be the height of that element. In this case, the parent is set to be `height: 40px` so he's matching that height. The line that does what I've described here is `line-height: 40px;`

[**Here's a JSFiddle isolating the vertical centering.**](http://jsfiddle.net/3EwSf/)

#### Other possibilities

You'll see that I centered the `a` horizontally and vertically in the very first JSFiddle I posted. That's usually the method I use, but of course, there's always more than one way to do things. The best method is probably dependent on the context of your project!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the `line-height: 40px` that centers vertically.  This won't look right if the text were ever to wrap.

Anchors are `display: block` so that padding is applied to a block-level element, rather than the default inline (try changing it to see how the appearance changes). The anchor will essentially "fill" it's container `LI` element, which is floated to keep things on the same line (while not "inline").